# Making image fit into table cell without going past the div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a flash card with an image on the top portion and text on the bottom. I've tried putting the image and text into a 1x2 table with the image on the top cell and the text on the bottom cell. I don't want the cell to expand to fit the image. I want the image to fit the cell. Currently, the image is covering up the card and pushes the text way down below the card. Here's what I have so far:

```css
body {
  background: #F17563;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #222;
}
label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}
.card div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.card .back {
  background: #222;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
label:hover .card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}
input {
  display: none;
}
 :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
label:hover :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://static.igre123.com/slike/28899-68381/turtle-attack!!!-*-*.jpg" alt="hi" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Front
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="back">Back</div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is a bit hard to read, but from what I understand, you don't need a table.

You should have a div that is styled to the size you want the card to be and a background image set to cover.

CSS

```
.card-background {
  background-image: url("http://static.igre123.com/slike/28899-68381/turtle-attack!!!-*-*.jpg");
  background-size: cover;

  //size of card
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for what you have is to set the table cell to an absolute width, then set the image inside it to 100% width. See example below. Here is the code I changed:

```
<td style="width:300px;">
    <img src="http://static.igre123.com/slike/28899-68381/turtle-attack!!!-*-*.jpg" alt="hi" style="width:100%;" />
</td>
```

```css
body {
  background: #F17563;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #222;
}
label {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms;
  transition: all 600ms;
  z-index: 20;
}
.card div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.card .back {
  background: #222;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
label:hover .card {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}
input {
  display: none;
}
 :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
label:hover :checked + .card {
  transform: rotateX(160deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(160deg);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:300px;">
            <img src="http://static.igre123.com/slike/28899-68381/turtle-attack!!!-*-*.jpg" alt="hi" style="width:100%;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Front
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="back">Back</div>
  </div>
</label>
```